# Compatible wire cable for laptop screen

Tags: display, motherboard, cable, laptop-display

While trying to replace my laptop screen, I have damaged the wire cable connecting the screen to the motherboard.

Consequently, I am trying to find and buy a new cable to replace the damaged one. I do not know how to go about that, my problem is that my laptop is not from a large compagny like Dell or Asus, it's an LDLC (this one : http://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00120537.html)

Here are the infos I could come up with:

- I have contacted LDLC (they cannot provide a new cable), they informed me that my computer chassis (base/ frame, I'm not sure what the correct word is) is a Clevo W251HNQ.
- The screen is a LP156WD1-TLB2
- Linux tells me (lshw) that my motherboard is a Dell Inc 0XD720 Edit : No! That's wrong
- Below is a photo of the "head" of the damaged cable: (I think the first line reads "Wire cable for LVDS").

Is someone had a clue how/where I can find a replacement cable, I would be very grateful.

[image]

Upon request, here is a couple of other pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is a part number on that label.  Why can't you just use that?

Comment: You mean the P/N? That would do it? The thing is, I cannot read it better than what you see on the photo! But for instance if I google search "6-43-W26A1", I don't seem to get anything.

Comment: Even if you have the full part number its a LDLC part number.  If they won't sell you a new cable then you are out of luck.  Your missing 5 characters out of that part number.  Honestly it sounds like you are out of luck.  The cable in question was likely built for the manufacture and only exists because of that fact.

Comment: That sounds like bad news! Are you saying all I have left to do is throw my laptop down the trash?

Comment: That is entirely up to you. Without the full part number you cannot even attempt to locate it.  You might be able to locate a broken laptop that uses the same cable in theory.

Comment: I hope someone else has a more optimistic answer! But say I had the full P/N, what would I do with it?

Comment: You would try to find it on say Ebay.

Comment: P/N: 6-43-W25A1-010-3H

Comment: Page 34 of this [disassembly guide](https://www.rm.com/_RMVirtual/Media/Downloads/NB320_-_Disassembly_Guide.pdf) is the only mention I could find of that part number online.

Comment: You could contact either Clevo or Sager with their product numbers (Clevo W251HNQ/Sager NP3250) to see if they stock the cable.

Comment: My question was put on hold. "Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs." I think that's what I did.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a standard LVDS (low voltage differential signalling) connector, commonly used for laptop LCD screens.

In which case, replacements can be found on-line. The only thing is to buy a cable that will fit in your laptop. Length does not have to be exact, but its always better to have a longer cable than one that is too short. You can't cut and splice these effectively, not without good expensive tools anyway..

According to the specs you will be looking for a 40pin 2CH 6-Bit LVDS cable. I would like you to post up pictures of both connections on the cable, to confirm that it is not a proprietary socket (highly doubt it as it's not apple).

LINKS: For two different types of motherboard connections. One is split for power

- http://www.ebay.com/itm/LVDS-CABLE-600mm-IPEX-40PIN-0-5mm-pitch-2ch-6bit-for-15-6inch-19inch-lcd-panel-/201037612448?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2ecec685a0
- http://www.ebay.com/itm/LVDS-CABLE-IPEX-40PIN-0-5mm-pitch-2ch-6bit-for-15-6inch-19inch-lcd-panel-/170912642004?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27cb2ff3d4

[image: http://www.panelook.com/LP156WD1-TLB2_LG%20Display_15.6_LCM_parameter_5699.html]

Also, I tried to find information on your motherboard... Dell Inc 0XD720 Couldn't find anything. It seems pretty old, used on a Dell Inspiron 6400... http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/dell-inspiron-6400-review-pics-spaecs/ It is Highly unlikely it is the same as the one on your computer. Hoping linux is just reporting false readings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have added a couple pictures, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I'm just gonna browse ebay now. See if I can find the right one for you.

Comment: And added a picture of the whole cable. Again, thanks a bunch. If you tell me what I need to look for (LVDS 40 pinch etc), I can look myself, please don't waste too much time.

Comment: Also, I can probably find out what my motherboard is exactly, if that helps.

Comment: I'm hoping someone more experienced steps in. I can't seem to find this particular motherboard end socket. Trying 1-CH 6 bit. Maybe that helps. and I'm not wasting time I'm learning about how annoying computer manufacturers are, so don't mind helping.

Comment: Wow, I just realized that I typed the linux command to find out what the motherboard is on the computer I'm using right now, which is an old Dell laptop. It's so dumb I'm ashamed to admit it! (:
Would it help if I tried to find out what the motherboard actually is?

Comment: It will help. Hopefully you can contact the maufacturer and get a replacemnt cable. The LCD socket plug on the wire is commonly used, But the motherboard end isn't. I suggest you take the wire to a computer repair shop (i.e not Best Buy, an actual computer mechanic), hopefully they can get one or fix the one you have.